# Using Google Sheets API v4 above the quota

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to find the pricing for Google Sheets API. The limit is 300 requests/min per project and there's also a per-user limit.

I read you can request a quota increase but I'm willing to pay with some pricing model so there's no cap on the number of requests. Is there any information on that?

You can take an example of [sheetdb.io](https://sheetdb.io), an app like that will need to send thousands of requests in a minute as it will be used by many users at the same time.

PS: I'm not looking for BigQuery, optimization, DBMS solution. The app is built around Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/limits):

> This version of the Google Sheets API has a limit of 500 requests per 100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user. Limits for reads and writes are tracked separately. There is no daily usage limit.
>
> To view or change usage limits for your project, or to request an increase to your quota, do the following:
>
> 1. If you don't already have a [billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account) for your project, then create one.
> 2. [Visit the Enabled APIs page of the API library](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/enabled) in the API Console, and select an API from the list.
> 3. To view and change quota-related settings, select **Quotas**. To view usage statistics, select **Usage**.

Comment: Yes, there's only an option to make a request to increase the quota, nothing about the pricing.

Comment: There's no public information about pricing - you have to make the request to Google with a valid justification, and they will come back to you with an answer which will include a pricing quote if they agree.